# How to improve this inline query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a sales-force developer, I got a requirement to write a SQL query and I did it, but the performance in very low. Could you please help me here?

My query is like this:

```
select col1, col2,col3,col4 
from table1 
where col1 is not null 
  and col2='ABC' 
  and (col3 IN (SELECT field1 FROM table 2) 
       OR col4 in('A','B','C'))
```

Is there someway I can optimize this for better performance?

**Update**

I used left outer join to achieve it, Is that the correct way?

Comment: Why don't you use `PARALLEL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these queries:

```
SELECT col1, col2,col3,col4 FROM TABLE1 T1 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.COL3 = T2.FIELD1)
   OR COL4 IN ('A','B','C'))

SELECT col1, col2,col3,col4 FROM TABLE1 T1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.COL3 = T2.FIELD1)
UNION
SELECT col1, col2,col3,col4 FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE COL4 IN ('A','B','C')
```

Comment: @ShankarPanda . . . I'm surprised this has been accepted.  These queries are not equivalent to the queries in the question (perhaps the question was edited?).